# Using a global function inside a class

Tags: c++, function, class, oop, global

I'm trying to study by myself the OOP and I wanted to know if what I am doing is correct or if it is an anti-pattern. Is it OK to use a global function inside a class? for example:

```
bool isMale(char s)
{
      if(s=='m')return true;
      else return false;
 }
 class person
 {
       string name; char sex;
       bool collocate()
      {
           if(isMale(sex))cout<<"He's a male!";
           else cout<<"She's not!";
       }
 }
```

I know this is a very stupid code but I was just trying to explain myself. Is it indicated to use global function inside a class or is it a bad-habit? Should I use other ways or is it OK?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to account for other option than male / female for sex? If not a Boolean would work just as fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it, yes, and it is not considered an anti-pattern. It is quite often an elegant solution as well.
It is also usually a good idea to wrap your global functions into a namespace

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with using global functions in C++; the language is a superset of C and global functions are C's bread and butter. A benefit of using a global function is that it doesn't rely on an object being instantiated before the function can be called. This can make the function far easier to test in isolation.

Generally when writing code in this fashion I put my functions into a class and make them static, though. This negates the possibility of writing a function with the same name as some standard library function since it's in a different namespace. i.e:

```
class Person
{
public:

    static bool isMale( char gender )
    {
        return gender == 'm';
    }

    bool collocate()
    {
        if( isMale( m_sex ) )
            cout << "He's a male!" << endl;
        else
            cout << "She's not!" << endl;
    }

private:

    /// m/f
    char m_sex;
    /// Person Name
    String m_name;
};
```

Comment: "the language is a superset of C and global functions are C's bread and butter."  I disagree with the implied reasoning here, as this implies that `malloc` is good as well, but the rest of this answer is good.

Answer (score 2):

Since this method seems to be intimately related to person class, it can be a static method of the class. If you can imagine needing the function without having person class included, and decide that the same function should indeed be used both for person class objects and for everything else, then a global function *in a suitable namespace* is better. If the method is used by many related classes, but does not seem to belong to any class, then the classes and these helper functions should be neatly in the same namespace.

```
 class person
 {
 private:

       string name; 
       char sex;

 public:
       static bool isMale(char s)
       {
          if(s=='m')return true;
          else return false;
       }

       bool collocate()
       {
           if(isMale(sex))cout<<"He's a male!";
           else cout<<"She's not!";
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it. Yes.  Not everything is an object in C++.

Answer (score 0):

This is ok (although isMale needs an argument). ^^
In fact, only functions that really need access to the representation of a class should be memberfunctions. That way, you have fewer functions to worry about if you change your class-representation while keeping its interface.